# Are CSS Masks available

Tags: css

Is it possible to have a mask in CSS

I was wondering if I could use a mask to do something like this.

http://www.ttmt.org.uk/face.png

It would be good if I could do it something like this.

```
    <div class="circle">
      <img src="face.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
```

If I can't do it like this, is the only other way to do it in Photoshop and then have a flat square image with the face in the circle inside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to work with the property `border-radius` and `overflow:hidden` on the container. Like this:

```
.circle {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border-radius:50%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Check this *D'oh* Demo http://jsfiddle.net/p57fs/

Comment: The reference I should have put in a /comment/ was: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/

Comment: @mori57 don't see your edit was the same time I'm adding info but feel free to add your link now :d

Comment: No worries. This newfound edit power's gone straight to my head! :) Nice and quick demo you have there. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS `border-radius` property either on the image itself if it's already cropped, or on the container div to "mask" the image.

## option 1

Use `border-radius` on the image itself. [See this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9vUGB/). This is simpler to implement with a single HTML tag, but you are not really masking the image this way (so your images need to be properly cropped).

## Option 2

Use `border-radius` on a container div. This gives you more control over where the image can be positioned. [see this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L44Q9/).

Note that the `border-radius` property is not supported on older browsers ( [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius#Browser_compatibility) ). If it's not supported, a square image will appear, so I guess the site would still remain functional